# is multi-hovering touch technology possible?

Tags: android, hover

It is a bit interesting to switch with android this days, I am interested in knowing if multi-hovering is really possible.

Base on some search:

1. From Cypress Technology in [Xperia Sola's Floating touch](http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/technologies/floating-touch/), multiple hover is not possible using the self-capacitance because of ghosting issue.
2. Currently Samsung Galaxy S4 has hovering capabilities using Synaptics S5000B controller but it only accepts 1 finger hover.
3. According to the rumor [multi-hovering touch feature on Galaxy S5](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/mobiles/news/samsung-galaxy-s5-said-to-come-with-fingerprint-sensor-hovering-touch-feature-473581) using the synaptics touch tech, it is possible. But was not included in the release, I am wondering how it works.

I would like to ask if someone can give me an additional insight/details about multiple hover, for example 4 fingers are hovering the screen. is multi-hover possible? This could be useful in some application in the future though.

Answer (score 0):

I did a research about this 2 years ago, and found a few hardware companies that made some breakthrough in this field, some of them already implemented their technologies in current products (just as you mentioned) but this is not enough...

I'm curious about this kind of technology too, In fact as a UX specialist, I can see endless possibilities for useful applications by delivering better user experiences for the users. but I'm not a hardware expert so it is hard for me to develop a concept or prototype, I'm currently working on it (I've got more technologies that I want to combine and implement into Multi-touch devices), I believe that multi-touch is not enough.

And as for my research, I found few companies that developing this kind of technology, but the technology itself is not enough, there should me more things on top of it to make it useful for everyone... anyway, take a look on them:

1.FingerTip by ST: http://youtu.be/tGdxfHGgQ9g

2.Fogale Sensation: http://youtu.be/11xHtVJhb6k

3.Atmel’s next-gen touch controllers (google it).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Hi, I edited my post and added some more information.

Comment: Well, that is a good information, thanks for sharing it @Avi-B.